# Django Class model access self

Tags: python, django

I'm using a django package that checks whether the browser is mobile. I want to apply it to `paginate_by` so on a mobile device there's less galleries using `self.request.mobile`. Here's the class:

```
class GalleryList(ListView):
    model = Gallery
    paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = 'galleries'
    category = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.mobile:
            self.template_name = 'mobile/gallery.html'
        qs = Gallery.objects.filter(visible=True,).order_by('-created','-hot')
        return qs
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the method `get_template_names` of `ListView` like the following:

```
def get_template_names(self):
    if self.request.mobile:
        return 'mobile/gallery.html'
    return 'normal/gallery.html'
```

EDIT:

For paginate by you can try this:

```
def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
    if self.request.mobile:
        return 5
    return 20
```

Comment: I have done what I want is to wrap the paginate so on a mobile device it gets 5 and on a desktop 20